# Extracting just the text out of HTML code in Java

Tags: java, html, text

I need to extract the text out of HTML on websites. Here is my code that I use to extract the HTML code.

```
public static void readFromWeb(String webURL) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(webURL);
        InputStream is =  url.openStream();
        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MalformedURLException("URL is malformed!!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear (at least IMO). What do you mean by "even though the file is local I want it to be able to do the same thing on non-local websites"? And how is your code related to the problem you are facing/asking about?

Comment: I meant I dont want to have to use html files and I want to also be able to use public websites. The code above extracts the html code and now I just need to take out the html part and leave the text

Comment: So you want to *parse* html structure and leave only text it represents. In that case use one of many HTML parsers. IMO Jsoup is one of best. Answer below shows contains demo of how you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSoup:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(readFromWeb("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
    }

    public static String readFromWeb(final String webUrl) throws IOException {
        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webUrl).get();
        return doc.text();
    }
}
```